# Why does printf concatenate two variables when outputing, but only if the length of the string is not specified?

Tags: c

Anyone know why printf concatenates these two variables when outputting, but only if the length of the string is not specified?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char myname[3] = "tim";
char myage[3] = "ten";
printf("myname is:%s \n", myname);
printf("myage is:%s \n", myage);
}
```

myname is:tim

myage is:tentim

...But when I don't specify the length of the strings it seems to work as I had expected, without printing both variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char myname[] = "tim";
char myage[] = "ten";
printf("myname is:%s \n", myname);
printf("myage is:%s \n", myage);
}
```

myname is:tim

myage is:ten

Comment: The length 3 is wrong, should be at least 4, including null character. This is unspecified behavior.

Comment: @AlexFarber That's not unspecified behaviour. Look at the comments to Alok Save's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not leaving enough room in your array for the null terminator.  In C, when you initialize a char array with a string of the exact same length, the null terminator is dropped.

```
char myname[3] = "tim"; // equivalent to char myname[3] = {'t','i','m'};
char myage[3] = "ten"; // equivalent to char myage[3] = {'t','e','n'};
```

Without the null terminator, the printf function doesn't know when to stop printing your string, so it keeps going to the next memory location after your `myage` array, which just happens to be the storage for your `myname` array.  The stack probably looks like this:

```
t <- beginning of myage
e
n
t <- beginning of myname
i
m
\0  <- a null terminator, by coincindence.
```

The fact that you don't get other garbage after the name is just a coincidence.  Anything might be stored after your `myname` array, but in your case it was a null character, so printf stopped printing.

If you don't specify a size for your array, then a size is chosen that is one greater than the length of the string so that the null terminator can be stored:

```
char myname[] = "tim"; // equivalent to myname[4] = {'t','i','m','\0'};
char myage[] = "ten";  // equivalent to myage[4] =  {'t','e','n','\0'};
```

Now your null terminators are put in place explicitly, and your stack looks like this:

```
t <- beginning of myage
e
n
\0 <- explicit null terminator
t <- beginning of myname
i
m
\0  <- explicit null terminator.
```

Now the printf function knows exactly when to stop printing.

Answer (score 6):

You declare the array to have size `3` but you try to store `4` elements in it. Since there is enough memory for only `3` elements there is no memory left for the last element(*the string null terminator `\0`*), this leaves your character array without a null terminator.
Note that character arrays in c are expected to be null terminated so that you can print them using `printf`. This is because `printf` simply walks through the character array till it encounters a `\0`. In your first example since the array was never `\0` terminated what you end up getting is Undefined behavior.(*Practically, `pintf` will keep printing till it encounters a `\0` and in the process reading beyond the bounds of memory allocated to the array*)

In second case since you do not specify the size by yourself the appropriate size is chosen depending on the number of elements specified in the string i.e: 4 and the `\0` terminate is in place.

Comment: "*You declare the array to have size 3 but you store 4 elements in it.*" Not according to the example at §6.7.9p32. The undefined behaviour isn't here. It's at the printf function.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue: What does §6.7.9p32 say? I have c99 handy and there is no §6.7.9.

Comment: §6.7.8p14: `An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally
enclosed in braces. Successive characters of the character string literal (including the
terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
elements of the array .`

Comment: @AlokSave It's not a C99 reference, though C99 has the same rule. §6.7.9p32 comes from C11: *EXAMPLE 8 The declaration
`char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";` defines ‘‘plain’’ `char` array objects s and t whose elements are initialized with character string literals.
This declaration is identical to
`char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`*

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` directive corresponds to an argument that points to a *string*. A string is a sequence of characters that ends at the first `'\0'`. However, you aren't giving the arrays in the first example enough space for a `'\0'`, so those arrays don't contain strings.

printf thinks that a string exists, and continues printing characters until it comes to that `'\0'` character which belongs at the end of a string. As previously stated, there is no `'\0'` character because there isn't space for one. Your code causes printf to access bytes outside of the bounds of your arrays, which is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The `myname[3]` and `myage[3]` suppose to have a place for terminating `\0`. Thus, you can actually store **only 2** symbols in each array.

In the second case compiler automatically sets size equal to `4` that is enough to store the strings.